# 4G router with low ping?

Tags: router, 4g, high-end

i'm looking for a 4G router that would provide low ping times. any suggestions?

i don't care about the price, size, portability, or looks, that's irrelevant. any 4G router that a can provide a great connection, in terms of low ping? (total throughput is not even important, as long as it's not terrible, it's only ping reduction i'm aiming for)

Comment: latency is location/ISP dependant though, unless you mean inside the local lan.

Comment: Adding on to @JourneymanGeek's point, usually the latency caused by your router is fairly negligible compared to the internet.